# Как запретить обновление Windows 1803

Tags: windows, windows-10, update

Данная проблема уже начала действовать на нервы. Каждый запуск устанавливается помощник по апгрейду до 1803. Служба обновлений выключается батником после каждого события 7040 по журналу. В реестре апдейты выключены. Твикерами обнову отключил. Отложил на максимальное количество дней. Всё равно стабильно вылезает окно с инфой о перезапуске через полчаса. Как это можно побороть?

Comment: Попробуйте мое решение, мне помогает https://github.com/Tarasovych/offWindows10Updates

Comment: Простите за столь вопиющую наглость, но почему бы не обновиться?)

Comment: @andreymal Карта Intel I219-V запускается несколько минут после стартапа ,да и этот геморой с приватностью